# Sequelize) When query findAll, it find from nonexistent column

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to find all information through user's id in my project. I set column name 'order_userid' and i intended search this column. But I got error below. I didn't create 'userId' column. Do I need to make new column or fix migration file?

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `order_context`, `price`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `userId` FROM `orders` AS `order` WHERE `order`.`order_userid` = 1;
(node:28648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'userId' in 'field list'
    at Query.formatError (/home/kyu/projects/Giftletters/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:265:16)
    at Query.run (/home/kyu/projects/Giftletters/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:77:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:28648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:28648) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is the codes.

```
 function (err, decoded) {
        
        if (err) {
          res.status(400).send(err)
        } else {
          order.findAll({
            where : {
              order_userid : decoded.id
            }
          })
```

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('orders', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      order_context: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      price: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('orders');
  }
};
```

migration file (20210721023329-order_userid.js)

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.addColumn('orders', 'order_userid', Sequelize.INTEGER);

    await queryInterface.addConstraint('orders', {
      fields: ['order_userid'],
      type: 'foreign key',
      name: 'FK_from_user_to_order',
      references: {
        table: 'users',
        field: 'id'
      },
      onDelete: 'cascade',
      onUpdate: 'cascade'
    });

  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.removeConstraint('orders', 'FK_from_user_to_order');
    await queryInterface.removeColumn('orders', 'order_userid');
  }
};
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you confirm, if you can see the newly added column in the database?

Comment: and please add your model file here too, that will clear things pretty much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with name mismatch, basically you've added the new column into the database using migration file as `order_userid` and in model file of order which is used to query from sequlize ORM you have named the column as `userId`.

So when sequlize fires the query it tries to fit the name which he has userId which database won't have. Please add model file in the question.

If you want a quick solution then change the code to, but I would suggest to make a proper solution:

```
 function (err, decoded) {
        
        if (err) {
          res.status(400).send(err)
        } else {
          order.findAll({
            attributes: [`id`, `order_context`, `price`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`],
            where : {
              order_userid : decoded.id
            }
          })
```